# How to make a Wordpress theme with a fully customizable site title?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

In the [Modernist](http://www.rodrigogalindez.com/themes/modernist/) Wordpress Theme the user can change the colour of the site title (in the Modernist theme it is the link inside `h1`).

You can even replace that text with a image.

I'm building a Wordpress theme form scratch and I would like to know how to build a Wordpress theme so that the user can change the colour of the site title and have to option to replace it for an image (e.g. png logo) using the dashboard.

Comment: Might want to try your question on the WordPress Stack Exchance: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress 3.0 supports custom headers http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_image_header

Other features can be added with theme options page, good totorial how to make this page is here http://forthelose.org/how-to-create-a-theme-options-page-for-your-wordpress-theme

Comment: Please don't follow that guide for building theme options, it's outdated. Better examples can be found on the WPSE site, i've linked to it in my other comment.